# XSLT 1.0: apply counter with context changes in self-transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, counter, nodes

I am having problems applying a counter to different contexts. I have the following XML - the focus should be on `E1EDL24/POSNR` elements. I have numerous `E1EDL24` elements with groups of the same `POSNR` and those are to be treated differently.

I have the following simplified XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DELVRY03>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <VBELN>0002012439</VBELN>
        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
        </E1ADRM1>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>10</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <CHARG>D5815</CHARG>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>XYZ</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>10</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <CHARG>D5815</CHARG>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>XYZ</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>10</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000722111</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D5915</CHARG>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>XYZ</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>70</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000392652</MATNR>
            <CHARG>L1514</CHARG>
            <LFIMG>216</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>70</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>3046920926522</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>XYZ</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>30</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000770600</MATNR>
            <CHARG>D1915</CHARG>
            <LFIMG>2</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>30</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057737409</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>XYZ</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>30</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000770600</MATNR>
            <CHARG>D1915</CHARG>
            <LFIMG>2</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>30</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057737409</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>XYZ</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
    </E1EDL20>
</IDOC>
</DELVRY03>
```

I apply the following XSLT to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="ISO-8859-1" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="E1EDL24[(POSNR = following::E1EDL24/POSNR or POSNR = preceding::E1EDL24/POSNR)
    and (MATNR = following::E1EDL24/MATNR or MATNR = preceding::E1EDL24/MATNR)]">
        <xsl:variable name="counter">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('90000',$counter)"/>
            </POSNR>
            <MATNR>
                <xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/>
            </MATNR>
            <MATWA>
                <xsl:value-of select="MATNR"/>
            </MATWA>
            <CHARG>
                <xsl:value-of select="CHARG"/>
            </CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>
                <xsl:value-of select="LFIMG"/>
            </LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>
                <xsl:value-of select="HIPOS"/>
            </HIPOS>
            <EAN11>
                <xsl:value-of select="EAN11"/>
            </EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DELVRY03>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <VBELN>0002012439</VBELN>
        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
        </E1ADRM1>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900001</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000722111</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D5815</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900002</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000722111</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D5815</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900003</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000722111</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D5915</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>70</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000392652</MATNR>
            <CHARG>L1514</CHARG>
            <LFIMG>216</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>70</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>3046920926522</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>XYZ</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900005</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000770600</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000770600</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D1915</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>2</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>30</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057737409</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900006</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000770600</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000770600</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D1915</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>2</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>30</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057737409</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
    </E1EDL20>
</IDOC>
```

But I expect the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DELVRY03>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
        <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
        <VBELN>0002012439</VBELN>
        <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
            <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
        </E1ADRM1>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900001</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000722111</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D5815</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900002</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000722111</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D5815</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900003</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000722111</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000722111</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D5915</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>6</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>10</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057734507</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24 SEGMENT="1">
            <POSNR>70</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000392652</MATNR>
            <CHARG>L1514</CHARG>
            <LFIMG>216</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>70</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>3046920926522</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>XYZ</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900001</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000770600</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000770600</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D1915</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>2</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>30</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057737409</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
        <E1EDL24>
            <POSNR>900002</POSNR>
            <MATNR>000000000000770600</MATNR>
            <MATWA>000000000000770600</MATWA>
            <CHARG>D1915</CHARG>
            <KDMAT/>
            <LFIMG>2</LFIMG>
            <HIPOS>30</HIPOS>
            <EAN11>7340057737409</EAN11>
            <E1EDL19 SEGMENT="1">
                <QUALF>BAS</QUALF>
                <PARAM/>
            </E1EDL19>
        </E1EDL24>
    </E1EDL20>
</IDOC>
```

Please see in the expected output the last two `E1EDL24` elements the `POSNR` value starts at `900001` again. But how can I achieve that the counter starts over? Right now it just keeps counting which I do not want.

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? I tried your XSLT at http://xsltransform.net/94hvTzn , and it works as expected; the last two elements show `900005` and `900006`. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Tim, no, the last two elements should show  `<POSNR>900001</POSNR>` and  `<POSNR>900002</POSNR>`, like I put in my expected output. But I do not know how I could "reset" the counter or change the context. I think it depends on how to nest the templates or for-eaches? thank you, Peter

Comment: Yes, it seems results may differ depending on the processor. Which XSLT processor are you using? Thanks!

Comment: Hello Tim, I am using XALAN, I also tried Saxon 6.5.5 and XSLTPROC but I always get the wrong result. The last two `E1EDL24` should have `<POSNR>900001</POSNR>`and `<POSNR>900002</POSNR>` (in the source XML they have `<POSNR>30</POSNR>). Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you could make looking up duplicates a bit quicker by means of keys

```
<xsl:key name="POSNR" match="E1EDL24" use="POSNR" />
<xsl:key name="MATNR" match="E1EDL24" use="MATNR" />
```

Then, your template match simplifies to the following:

```
<xsl:template match="E1EDL24[key('POSNR', POSNR)[2] and key('MATNR', MATNR)[2]]">
```

Then, as a first attempt, try changing the `counter` variable to this

```
    <xsl:variable name="counter">
        <xsl:number count="E1EDL24[key('POSNR', current()/POSNR)[2] and key('MATNR', current()/MATNR)[2]]" />
    </xsl:variable>
```

If that doesn't work because of the processor you are using, try this instead

```
<xsl:variable name="counter" 
              select="count(preceding::E1EDL24[key('POSNR', current()/POSNR)[2] and key('MATNR', current()/MATNR)[2]]) + 1" />
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, that works well. The counter I had to adapt (I had to choose version 2 because 1 my Oxygen did not like) as follows: `count(preceding::E1EDL24[HIPOS = current()/HIPOS][key('POSNR', current()/POSNR)[2] and key('MATNR', current()/MATNR)[2]]) + 1` in order to have it restart at value `900001` at the last two `E1EDL24`. I am not so familiar with keys. What does the `[2]` in the keys actually mean? `[1]` would only select the first occurence but `[2]` I can't figure out because it selects more than 2 if it has to... Thank you again, peter

Comment: The `[2]` is not actually in the key. The key returns a node-set of nodes that have the same value as the current element. The `[2]` then checks if this node-set has a second node. In other words, do two or more nodes exist with the same value. Using keys is often preferred as they are much more efficient at looking up values in the document.